# is there a book with a chapter on convergence consistency and stability for some specific numerical methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

The methods Im interested in are :

- Euler's Explicit and Implicit method
- Lax-Wendroff's Method
- Crank-Nicolson's Method

even online lecture notes with analysis of these would be great. thanks !

Comment: The second and third are methods for PDE. Is that the context you want to have considered in the references?

Comment: @LutzL Actually I only know them as methods for approximating solutions of ODE's

Comment: @LutzL here's the LW scheme that I'm talking about  : $h$ is the step we subdivide an interval $(a,b)$ into many $(t_i,t_{i+1})$ with $t_0 = a,\,\, t_{N} = b$, the eqn is $y' =f(t,y)$, $f$ is a 'nice' function then here's the algorithm : 

$$t_{n+1} = t_{n} + h,\, 0 \leq n \leq N-1, \,\, L_n = hf(t_n,y_n), \,\, y_{n+1} = y_{n} +hf(t_n+\frac{h}{2},y_n+\frac{L_n}{2})$$

$y_{n+1}$ approximates $y(t_{n+1})$

Comment: I know [Lax-Wendroff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method) as a method to approximate the Burgers equation and similar, [Crank-Nicolson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method) is usually introduced to solve the heat equation and similar. If you formulate it as method of lines, it reduces to a system of ODE, but that is not the primary problem statement.

Comment: That is the explicit midpoint method, or improved Euler method. It may be used in one of the variations of the LW scheme in the configuration of the time step. You then have probably the usual misconception to give the Heun, explicit trapezoidal, modified Euler method another name (because 3 names is not enough?) because the time step of CR is configured like the implicit trapezoidal method?

Comment: @LutzL thanks those were the keywords (midpoint, heun...) that I needed for googling.

Comment: First address is Hairer/Nørsett/Wanner: *Solving ODE I: Nonstiff problems*, which discusses this extensively. Or read the original 1901 paper by Kutta, he also discussed the next order terms and what that might mean for the numerical solution.